# Docker running out of space despite the server having enough space

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ckan

We have a docker-ckan installation on a cloud server. Recently, we have been having issues with docker running out of disk space. However, when we run "df -h" it says that we still have 23gb left. I'm not sure why this is happening and any suggestions would help!

Log error:

```
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/tmp/default//sessions/container_file_lock/
```

```
$df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           394M  600K  393M   1% /run
/dev/vda1       137G  108G   23G  83% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           394M     0  394M   0% /run/user/1002
```

Comment: on many systems /tmp is mounted as a tmpfs (in ram)

Comment: Hello @C1sc0, thanks for replying! I'm very new to docker though and not really sure what that means...